# talk announcement poster and website image

Tags: posters

I am looking for a template/document class to create small (about 40 cm x 60 cm) talk posters and -through the use of an option- the corresponding images for the website of our university department (chemistry).

I have found a couple of good examples here

- [Conference Announcement Poster](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41209/conference-announcement-poster)
- [Fit text to a region of a document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351402/fit-text-to-a-region-of-a-document#351451)

but can't really run either of them. Surely I am missing something.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! What happens if you try to compile one of these example? What error do you get? For your first link ([the code in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41220/116691)), I had to comment `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{lorenzattractor01}` out (line 32) since I don't have this image, but then everything works fine.

Comment: As per you second link, working with [the code as asked in the question, not the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/351402/116691), I had to remove remove `\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{cmbd_watermark}` on line 18 for the same reason, and import `uarial.sty` from [here](http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/fonts/urw/arial/latex/uarial.sty) (simply save the file `uarial.sty` and place it into your working directory).

Comment: @jchd: thank you for the quick response! In the first link ("carolina"), we have the source in the grey box that produces this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwOp5.png but; however, I would like the top image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNz3Z.png) for which there is no source and both links given in the question are currently dead.